# How to make searches not appear at the bottom of the window

Tags: search

When I press `n` or `N` to find the next match, it often happens that the window is redrawn such that the next match is displayed on the bottom-most or top-most line on the screen, and I have to scroll a few lines further to see enough context to know if I actually want to edit that line.

Is there a way to force the matches to be displayed such that a few surrounding lines are always visible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check if `set scrolloff=5` is what you need.

```
    Minimal number of screen lines to keep above and below the cursor.
    This will make some context visible around where you are working.  If
    you set it to a very large value (999) the cursor line will always be
    in the middle of the window (except at the start or end of the file or
    when long lines wrap).
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `scrolloff` is the right answer.

Although when searching I usually prefer doing `zz` (scroll the current line to the middle)

And when doing confirmed substitution I usually prefer doing <kbd>Ctrl e</kbd> (scrolling one line)

Answer (score 2):

The following mappings were adapted from Drew Neil's *Practical Vim*:

```
:nnoremap <Leader>n nzz
:nnoremap <Leader>N Nzz
```

They will make `n` go to the next match as usual and `<Leader>n` will go to the next match, centering the screen. You could also drop `<Leader>` from the mapping to change the defaults and have (next) searches also centered.

Comment: You probably want `nnoremap`.

Comment: I actually hesitated there. I'd probably also want it centered in visual mode, not so much in operator-pending mode. The book says `:noremap` and in the end I decided to quote verbatim.

Comment: I recall having problems with even the normal-mode mapping (when I had it on `n`/`N`) 6 years ago (something like `cgn` would insert `zz`, which I can't explain unless `gn` uses some path that executes mappings on `n`). Anyway

Comment: The problems you mention may have been the motivation for the `<Leader>` mappings. I couldn't reproduce them but Vim has improved in those 6 years.